# Query by two column version number in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two columns called major and minor that I am trying to do greater and less than queries on. They represent versions. So for version 2.1, the 2 is in the major column and 1 is the minor column. How can I do these queries? I would like to avoid creating a new column.

The issue is if I query `Model.where('major > ? and minor > ?', 3, 4)`, I won't get 4.1 or 5.2 because the minor is less than 4.

I am using rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9. Also, the versions don't get much complicated than number.number (ex. 2.9 or 4.3) so lets assume that they are all in that style.

Comment: Give a pseudocode.. Pls

Comment: Your DB engine name ? MySql ?

Comment: activerecord query on postgres

Comment: How much does performance matter here? This would be easier to accomplish in Ruby than SQL.

Comment: performance isn't a huge factor @AndyWaite

Comment: In that case @MCBama's suggestion seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct SQL query would be as follows:

```
major > :major -- check for bigger major
OR (major = :major AND minor > :minor) -- check within the same major
```

You can use it in ActiveRecord all right with the [placeholder conditions,](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions) though you probably should remove the comments (the parts of line after the `--`).

Example:

```
MyProductWithVersion.where('major > :major OR (major = :major AND minor > :minor)',
  major: 2, minor: 1)
```

Comment: That's not a Rails ActiveRecord query, so yes it does need explanation

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly a specific query like you're probably looking for, but an easy way to get what you want is this:

```
Model.all.select { |m| "#{m.major}.#{m.minor}".to_f > version_number}
```

Which collects all models with version number greater than `version_number`